# Hierarchical Query is classifying the mid-level category as top level

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has 3 level hierarchical data, however my query is classifying the levels incorrectly.

My query:

```
SELECT  t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3
FROM sds_test AS t1
LEFT JOIN sds_test AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN sds_test AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.ID;
```

The category Museum and Arts schools are getting an extra row as they are top level category which is something I want to eliminate. If I put level 2 is not NULL, it messes up those category's which has a single top level e.g. Aviation

**Desired Result** Museum and Arts School should not be a top level category and should not have a separate row for them.

[image: Actual Results Expected]

I am not sure how to solve this issue, as CTE is also getting me the similar results. I tried using case

`case when parent_id = NULL then`
which is again not giving me the desired results.

SQL query to regenerate the table:

```
create table sds_test (id int, name varchar(30), parent_id int);
insert into sds_test values(1, 'Educational Institute', NULL);
insert into sds_test values(2, 'Speciality Schools', 1);
insert into sds_test values(3, 'Arts School', 2);

insert into sds_test values(4, 'Restraunts', NULL);
insert into sds_test values(5, 'Asian Restraunts', 4);
insert into sds_test values(6, 'malasian Rest', 5);

insert into sds_test values(7, 'Recreational', NULL);
insert into sds_test values(8, 'Museum', 7);

insert into sds_test values(9, 'Aviation', NULL);
```

Comment: Please show your actual results and the results you want.

Comment: added the results needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were very close:

```
SELECT  t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3
FROM sds_test AS t1
LEFT JOIN sds_test AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN sds_test AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.ID
WHERE t1.parent_id IS NULL
```

results in:

```
lev1                    lev2                lev3    
Educational Institute   Speciality Schools  Arts School
Restraunts              Asian Restraunts    malasian Rest
Recreational            Museum              NULL
Aviation                NULL                NULL
```

All I did was add the condition that the item in `t1` should not have a parent.

This does clearly not match the desired output. I wonder why *Aviation* should not be in there?

Comment: Thank you !!! Yes I was very close, should have thought about it. The image got cut off I believe. Aviation should be there.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well high praise for having a question with the table and data declarations, those are often missing. A pity that the result image got cropped.